# How to open new buffer instead of current via elisp?

Tags: minibuffer, ido, ibuffer

I want to bind key when in `ido-switch-buffer` to open `ibuffer` instead, but I do not understand how to make that with elisp. Here's my config:

```
(defun my-open-ibuffer ()
  "Open ibuffer from ido-switch-buffer"
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
  (ibuffer-other-window))

(defun bind-ido-keys ()
  "Keybindings for ido mode."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-H-S-c") 'my-open-ibuffer))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook #'bind-ido-keys)
```

It looks like when I call `(minibuffer-keyboard-quit)` to close `ido-minibuffer` function stops evaluating and not running next `(ibuffer-other-window)` that should open `ibuffer`. If I comment out `(minibuffer-keyboard-quit)` it works as supposed - open new ibuffer window with not closed minibuffer. But I want minibuffer to be closed, and config described above only closes minibuffer and not triggering ibuffer opening.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like I figured it out by myself, and great thanks for this to abo-abo's brilliant post about [callback-quit](http://oremacs.com/2015/07/16/callback-quit/)

The trick is in `minibuffer-quit-and-run` macro described below, if anyone had the same issues with running smth with minibuffer closing:

```
(defmacro minibuffer-quit-and-run (&rest body)
  "Quit the minibuffer and run BODY afterwards."
  `(progn
     (run-at-time nil nil
                  (lambda ()
                    (put 'quit 'error-message "Quit")
                    ,@body))
     (minibuffer-keyboard-quit)))

(defun my-open-ibuffer ()
  "Open ibuffer from ido-switch-buffer"
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-quit-and-run (ibuffer-other-window)))



(defun bind-ido-keys ()
  "Keybindings for ido mode."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-H-S-c") 'my-open-ibuffer))
```